# Struts2 date parsing

Tags: java, struts2, datepicker

I have a form with a field that uses a date/time picker which produces a hidden field with the full date & time in the 'British' format **dd/MM/yy HH:mm** through the use of javascript. This is submitted to a struts2 action whch has getters & setters for the field with operate on java.util.Date.

In the JSP:

```
<s:form>

  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="myDate" value="08/05/11 16:00" />
  <s:submit />

</s:form>
```

In the action

```
public class MyAction 
{

   public void setMyDate(Date d)
   {
      this.d = d;
   } 

   public Date getMyDate()
   {
      return d;
   }

}
```

As expected in Firefox when I submit the form struts automatically parses the date and I end up with a Date object in the action with the correct date.

However in Google Chrome when I submit the form the date is parsed as if it is in the US format **MM/dd/yy HH:mm** and as a result I get 5th August instead of 8th May.

Inspecting the HTTP headers sent by both browsers reveales that despite my OS language set to en_GB google chrome still sends the 'Accept-Language' header as en_US which means struts must be using this to determine what date format to use.

I can only assume this is a bug in Google Chrome however given that I don't have the freedom to fix google chrome is there a way in Struts 2 that I can specify a fixed date format which tells Struts the format it should use to parse dates in form parameters?

Comment: Have you tried using `request_locale` parameter set to the desired lang? This parameter sets a session variable `WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE` and, for my application, it overrides 'Accept-Language' set language. Hope it helps... http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/I18nInterceptor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid misinterpretation of dates caused by different [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) values, I would go with an unambiguous and well-defined method of representing dates and times. This is what the **[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** standard covers.

Unfortunately I don't think Struts2 can convert to [Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) given this representation "out of the box". For date conversion, by default, [Struts2 uses the SHORT format for the Locale associated with the current request](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-BuiltinTypeConversionSupport).

I guess you could try finding a plugin that already converts ISO 8601 dates or a simple approach would just be to [write your own](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-CreatingaTypeConverter).

Comment: I have gone with creating a custom TypeConverter for the ISO standard, its a bit disappointing struts doesn't allow you to specify an unambiguous format but the TypeConverter solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Joda Time API.](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) It fully supports the [ISO 8601 standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm) and has an extensive API for locales, timezones, conversions, etc. I use it for all of my date-time manipulations in all of my applications (including Struts 2).